# Formatting problem

Tags: output-formatting

Writing:

```
"x =" <> ToString[1/2]
```

I get:

[image]

and even if I tried in the forum I could not find a way to get rid of this problem, namely to obtain:

[image]

or better still:

[image]

Thank you!

---

Last formatting problem. Writing:

```
"x =" TextForm[1/2 q (l - 2 \[Xi])]
```

I get:

[image]

where the outer bracket is completely useless. Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: What are you looking to get?

Comment: Try `"x =" TextForm[1/2]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
"x = " <> ToString[1 / 2, StandardForm]  (* or *)
Row[{"x = ", StandardForm[1/2]}]
```

[image]

```
"x =" <> ToString[1/2 q (l - 2 \[Xi]), StandardForm] (* or *)
Row[{"x =", StandardForm[1/2 q (l - 2 \[Xi])]}]
```

[image]

You can use `TraditionalForm` in place of `StandardForm` above to get similar outputs.

Comment: @TeM, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

Something like 
    `ToString["x =" TextForm[1/2]]`
produces a 3 string with text formatted as necessary, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Please note that the output is text and it's poorly formatted i.e. division is made with "-" placed between strings with 1 and 2.